# How to pull information from one table into text boxs based on primary key from another table?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
protected void custo_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();

    if (appo_fname.Text != null || appo_lname.Text != null || appo_num.Text != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        MySqlDataReader myReader = null;

        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT customers.First_name,customers.Last_name,customers.Phone_num From customers INNER JOIN appointments On customers.Phone_num=appointments.Phone_num Where customers.Phone_num='" + search_txt.Text+"' ", conn);

        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {  
            appo_fname.Text = (myReader["customers.First_name"].ToString());
            appo_lname.Text = (myReader["customers.Last_name"].ToString());
            appo_num.Text = (myReader["customers.Phone_num"].ToString());
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I am trying to connect between 2 tables with the same primary key, so when I enter a phone number in search textbox it will check if the number exist in the  other table and if it is so I will get f.name, l.name and phone into other text boxes in order to insert the customer information without typing all over but something is not working in my code, it skips over the code inside the "while"

Comment: My phone number is `"'; drop database DB_Name()'"`

Comment: Change your while statement into 
            do {if (myReader.HasRows)
            {
                appo_fname.Text = (myReader["customers.First_name"].ToString());
            appo_lname.Text = (myReader["customers.Last_name"].ToString());
            appo_num.Text = (myReader["customers.Phone_num"].ToString());
            }
        } while (myReader.NextResult());

Comment: Is there is any exception or just there no data returned by the query, I think the code here is OK just you have to be care about sql injection. You could run the query in the sq management studio and check if  the query could return  something.

Comment: tanks kami and tarek, now its working on the table that created in the join, but how can i change my query so it compare any phone number i put in the text box to the phone numbers in customers table?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following statements

```
appo_fname.Text = (myReader["customers.First_name"].ToString());
appo_lname.Text = (myReader["customers.Last_name"].ToString());
appo_num.Text = (myReader["customers.Phone_num"].ToString());
```

into:

```
appo_fname.Text = (myReader["First_name"].ToString());
appo_lname.Text = (myReader["Last_name"].ToString());
appo_num.Text = (myReader["Phone_num"].ToString());
```

(drop the table name before the column name)
Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection because you are creating your select statement with string concatenation. You should pass the phone number as a parameter to your select statement.

I can't see how you are creating the conn object, but I'd make sure it is done by a 'using' statement.